# Amcharts export: Loading error on libs

Tags: javascript, html, amcharts

I am working on a project using amcharts, and  I'm trying to use the Export features.
I linked to my project export.js and export.css according the userguide, in this way i can finally see the download button/export button in the top right of my charts so the libs are correctly loaded.
Unfortunately i can't get any image or xslx from that, opening a console it comes 4 errors related to loading error on the 4 libraries useful to work with export:

- fabric.js
- FileSaver.js
- jszip.js
- pdfmake.js

if I try to attach manually pdfmake library, I can solve the dependency issue, but if I try to do the same with the others, the console still reports problems about loading error libs.

How I could solve this?

Comment: Are the libraries in the correct location? What kind of error are you getting? Can you create a fiddle that reproduces this?

Comment: Hi xorspark, the error is this:

amCharts[export]: Loading error on http://localhost:8091/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/pdfmake/pdfmake.min.js
export.min.js:1 AmCharts [export]: Could not find "fabric" in: [object Window]
export.min.js:1 AmCharts [export]: Gave up waiting for "fabric" in: [object Window]

I can't include those libraries, I'm able only to load the pdf one

Comment: Can you post your chart code+config? It sounds like it can't find the libraries. If you disabled autoload or changed the paths where the libraries are located, make sure they're in the correct place. You can find more information about loading the libraries in the export plugin's [github page](https://github.com/amcharts/export#1-automatic-preferred)